# Highlight in beamer in the table of contents the line corresponding to the forthcoming section

Tags: beamer, sectioning, highlighting

I am preparing a presentation with beamer. Before each new section I show the table of contents. I wonder how can I somehow highlight the line of the table of contents with corresponds to the new section to appear

Answer (score 53, accepted):

To highlight the section of the next slides in a ToC you need to start the section officially using `\section` and then use `\tableofcontents[currentsection]` in a frame:

```
\section{Foobar}
\frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
```

There is also other options to `\tableofcontents[<option>]`, like `currentsubsection` and `hideallsubsections` as well, all of them simply change the `sectionstyle`, `subsectionstyle` and/or `subsubsectionstyle`.

They are all explain in the `beamer` manual, page 100pp. Here the important part:

> `sectionstyle=⟨style for current section⟩/⟨style for other sections⟩` specifies how sections should be displayed. Allowed `⟨styles⟩` are `show`, `shaded`, and `hide`. The first will show the section title normally,
>   the second will show it in a semi-transparent way, and the third will completely suppress it. You can also omit the second style, in which case the first is used for all sections (this is not really useful).
>
> `subsectionstyle=⟨style for current subsection⟩/⟨style for other subsections in current section⟩/
>   ⟨style for subsections in other sections⟩` specifies how subsections should be displayed. The same styles
>   as for the sectionstyle option may be given. You can omit the last style, in which case the second
>   also applies to the last, and you can omit the last two, in which case the first applies to all.

Comment: great! can we also hide subsubsections? I tried it but does not work

Comment: @flow: `\tableofcontents[currentsection,hideallsubsections,subsubsectionstyle=hide]`

Comment: and sorry and last question, how can one highlight just subsection?

Comment: @flow: You mean only the current subsection?

Comment: yes, exactly, only the current subsection

Comment: Use `currentsubsection` instead or after `currentsection`.

Comment: is there a way to highlight a given section, different from current ? in other words: is is possible to obtain what is asked above without changing the section ?

Comment: How I remove the the table of contents after the end of the whole section?